# Solve differential equation $ x^2 y''- 4y=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problem**: $ x^2 y'' - 4y=0 $ with condition $y(0)=0,y(1)=1$
>
> **Solution**:It is  homogeneous ordinary differential equation with variable cofficient
>
> Put $x=e^z$

Am I doing right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: This is a Euler-Cauchy type problem, so let

$$y = x^m$$

Now, substitute into the original ODE and solve.

Can you take it from here?

Hover over the following for the spoiler!

> $\displaystyle y(x) = c_1x^{m_1} + c_2 x^{m_2} = c_1 x^{\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{17}}{2}} + c_2 x^{\dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{\sqrt{17}}{2}}$

Comment: What is solution with condition  $y(0)=0,y(1)=1$

Comment: Did you mean $y(0)$ and $y'(1)$?

Comment: Here we have $y(0)$ and $y(1)$

Comment: Put those boundary conditions in and you get no solution. Put $x=0$ and $x = 1$ and see what you have for $c_1$ and $c_2$. Something seems wrong with those. You have two unknowns and you need two ICs to solve for them. Those BCs do not provide that.

Comment: With $y(0)=0$, we get $ 0=0$ .And with $y(1)=1 $,we get $ c1+c2=1$

Comment: So, you only have 1-equation and 2-unknowns. That is exactly what I am saying. Are you sure those are the given boundary conditions. For two unknowns, we need two equations to solve them.

Comment: Then ,I think there is some printing mistake in the boundary conditions (given in the book).thanks for your helpful comments

Comment: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: Nice hint, as usual, and great follow-up! +1

Comment: Did you POET? ;-) Hope your day was great, and your evening even better!

Comment: Two more weeks to spend, almost (shy a day), starting this coming Tuesday, I'll need to spend at the hospital (outpatient)...again. But I've been promised *that's all.* PERIOD. No: "'bout two weeks" turning into seven weeks! :-| (But I did actually get as much, if not more, done during those weeks than since...e.g. a lot of reading, I even got more done around the house, interestingly. So another slow-down for me at MSE, which is actually sort of welcomed...That is, I welcome the "less time at MSE" part!)